# Facebook login flutter app error with native login

Tags: facebook, flutter

I am trying to integrate facebook login with Flutter. Facebook login working with FacebookLoginBehavior.webViewOnly but I want to login with native dialog. This is not woking in flutter. (iOS only)....

```
Future<bool> facebookLogin(
   BuildContext context, bool isCoach, AuthMode authMode) async {

 final facebookLogin = FacebookLogin();
 facebookLogin.loginBehavior = FacebookLoginBehavior.nativeOnly;
 final result = await facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(['email']);
 print(result.status);
 if (result.status == FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn) {
  var _token = result.accessToken.token;

   return true;
  }
 return false;

}




Logs: flutter: FacebookLoginStatus.cancelledByUser
```

Comment: Did you try in simulator or real device? And do have Facebook application in that decvice?

Comment: We tried on both Simulator and Real Device. Results are same. And yes we do have FB app

Comment: @PraneethDhanushkaFernando I am facing same issues in Android having facebook app installed in my real device

Answer (score 1):

As per the issue list for the plugin this is a bug for iOS 13 (https://github.com/roughike/flutter_facebook_login/issues/195)

Use the [device_info](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info) package and you can put the following check for the iOS 13 device so the rest of the world enjoys the native view

```
if (Platform.isIOS){
  DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
  IosDeviceInfo iosInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
  String iosSystemVersion = iosInfo.systemVersion;

  if (iosSystemVersion.startsWith('13')){
     print('Running on IOS version $iosSystemVersion. Forcing facebook login to be webViewOnly');
     _facebookSignIn.loginBehavior = FacebookLoginBehavior.webViewOnly;
  }
}
```